# Space formed by difference between lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to write a program that takes in two lines in parametric form (an offset point and direction vector) and a constant number. It outputs pairs of s and t (the magnitude of the lines' direction) that when evaluated on the lines will yield two points (one on each line) with a distance of the constant number.

To do this I planned on taking the difference between the two lines. This results in a plane containing the two directions and the point of the difference between the two offsets. I then thought to intersect this plane with a sphere at the origin of this space with radius of the desired distance. The resultant circle would contain all the pairs of magnitudes when solved for the original points that made up the point in the difference space.

The problem is that this doesn't result in pairs with the desired distance all of the time. When the vectors are orthogonal it works, otherwise the range of the distances between points increases. I suspect that this is because the space formed by the difference of the lines is warped and requires an ellipsoid instead of a sphere or calculate the correct distance.

How can I form the correct ellipsoid given the lines, and for bonus points, solve for the oval collision between the ellipsoid and the plane? I'm open for taking a different approach if you see an easier way to solve for all line segments between two lines with a given magnitude.

Please be sure to explain your ideas as best as you can without jargon, I'm a senior in high school. This is for a personal project. Here are my equations:

Line 1: $o_1 + s\mathbf i$,

Line 2: $o_2 + t\mathbf j$.

Surface: $\{s\mathbf i - t\mathbf j + o_1 - o_2 \mid s, t \in \mathbb R\}$,

Circle Center -- origin projected on plane,

Circle Radius -- desired distance is hypotenuse of the line between the circle center and the origin and the line between the circle center and any point on the circle.

Comment: I think your question might be interesting, but I also find it very hard to understand. Let me ask some clarifying questions. You start with two lines and a constant $c$. Your starting lines are $\{ P + s \mathbf u : s \in \mathbb R\}$ and $\{ Q + t \mathbf v : t \in \mathbb R\}$. You want to find $(s, t)$ pairs corresponding to points $A = P + s\mathbf u $ on the first line and $B = Q + t\mathbf v $ with some property....but I can't understand *what* property. Is it that the distance from $A$ to $B$ is exactly $c$?

Comment: And when you say "taking the difference between two lines", what do you mean? Subtraction of lines isn't usually defined. And I cannot make sense of the rest. What is "the point of the difference between the two offsets"? What are the "offsets"? You haven't mentioned them earlier. Also: are your lines in the plane, or in 3-space? When you say "This results in a plane containing the..." do you mean that it results in a *surface* containing these things, or an actual plane? If a plane, is it a plane in 3-space?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification. Yes, the desired property is that the distance between points A and B is the constant c. By the difference between the lines I mean the opposite of the Minkowski sum. If you subtract the lines in parametric form, it forms a plane with the two variables s and t, contains P - Q and has a normal of U crossed with V. Yes, this forms a plane in 3D space. The point of the difference of the two offsets is defined as P - Q in your notation. The offsets are P and Q, the offsets of the parametric lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm going to use the names/notation I used in my comments.

Now to simplify things, I'm going to assume that $P$ and $Q$ are chosen so that the segment $PQ$ is perpendicular to the vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$, i.e., they're the points, on the two lines, that are as close as possible.

Next, I'm going to shift the origin to be at $(P + Q)/2$, the midpoint of the two. That makes the plane contain points of the form 
$$
s\mathbf u - t \mathbf v + (P - (-P)) = s\mathbf u + t \mathbf v + 2P.
$$
The origin, projected on this plane, projects to the point $R = 2P$. Can you see why?

A point $X$ is on your sphere if 
$$
\|R\|^2 + \|X - R\|^2 = c^2
$$ 
So let's look at the point $X(s, t) = s\mathbf u + t \mathbf v + 2P$ and see what that equation says about $s $ and $t$, assuming, for the moment, that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal. Let $r = \|R\|$.

\begin{align}
\|R\|^2 + \|X-R\|^2 &= c^2\\
r^2 + (s^2 + t^2) &= c^2 \\
(s^2 + t^2) &= c^2 - r^2
\end{align}

[Where, in the computation above, did I use that $u$ and $v$ were perpendicular?]

Now let's look, for such a pair $s, t$, at the points 
$A = s\mathbf u + P$ and $B = t\mathbf u - P$. The squared distance between them is the length of 
$A - B$, i.e., 
$$
\|s\mathbf u + P - (t\mathbf v - P)\|^2 = \|s\mathbf u - t\mathbf v + 2P\|^2 = s^2 + t^2 + r^2
$$
which, by the previous calculation, is just $c^2$ as desired.

Note: I computed that last squared distance using dot products: $|\mathbf q|^2 = \mathbf q \cdot \mathbf q$; in this case, that gave me
\begin{align}
\|s\mathbf u - t\mathbf v + 2P\|^2 
&= (s\mathbf u - t\mathbf v + 2P) \cdot (s\mathbf u - t\mathbf v + 2P)\\
&= s^2 \mathbf u\cdot \mathbf u - 2st\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v + 2s \mathbf u\cdot 2P + t^2 \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v -2t \mathbf v \cdot P + 4 P \cdot P
\end{align}

In this situation, the dot products among $u$, $v$, and $P$ are all zero, because they are three perpendicular vectors.

Now let's look at all that again, without the assumption about $u$ and $v$. The squared distance from $A$ to $B$ is still 
length of 
$A - B$, i.e., 
\begin{align}
\|s\mathbf u + P - (t\mathbf v - P)\|^2 
&= (s\mathbf u - t\mathbf v + 2P) \cdot (s\mathbf u - t\mathbf v + 2P)\\
&= s^2 \mathbf u\cdot \mathbf u - 2st\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v + 2s \mathbf u\cdot 2P + t^2 \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v -2t \mathbf v \cdot P + 4 P \cdot P
\end{align}
but this no longer simplifies as nicely. You want this squared distance to be $c^2$, so let's write that down and simplify a bit:
\begin{align}
s^2 \mathbf u\cdot \mathbf u - 2st\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v + 2s \mathbf u\cdot 2P + t^2 \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v -2t \mathbf v \cdot P + 4 P \cdot P &= c^2\\
s^2 \mathbf u\cdot \mathbf u - 2st\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v + 2s \mathbf u\cdot 2P + t^2 \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v -2t \mathbf v \cdot P + 2r^2 &= c^2\\
s^2 \mathbf u\cdot \mathbf u - 2st\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v + 2s \mathbf u\cdot 2P + t^2 \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v -2t \mathbf v \cdot P + r^2 &= c^2-r^2
\end{align}
If you compute values for all the dot products, you get an equation of the form 
\begin{align}
s^2 \alpha - 2st\beta + 2s \gamma + t^2 \delta v -2t \epsilon + r^2 &= (c^2 - r^2)
\end{align}
which is the equation of the ellipse that you should be looking at in the plane you've created. With some algebraic shuffling, you can surely write this in the form 
$$
(X - R)^t M (X - R) = c^2 - r^2
$$
where $A$ is a matrix whose columns are probably something like $\mathbf u, \mathbf v, P$ and $M$ is something like $A^t A$, but I'm going to leave this last part to you; work by analogy with the case where $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular.

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented the formula and it works perfectly. I'm glad to know that my intuition was correct -- and that I was dealing with an ellipsoid instead of a sphere. Your explanations are great, I would give a +1 if I had the reputation to do that.

Comment: Glad to have been of some help. Having done so, I want to make a suggestion: look at how I rephrased your question, and compare it to what you originally wrote. You'll see that I gave names to things, wrote explicit formulas, and stated the goal clearly. If you'd asked your question that way, you'd probably have gotten a response much sooner, as well as (perhaps) clarifying the ideas in your head in the course of writing the question. Although learning more math is more fun, learned to express math clearly is a *terrific* skill, one worth practicing.